# Why are my server settings not being read after I publish?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

I'm trying to create a Windows service using dotnet core 3.1. The settings work (i.e., `_serverAddress` shows `localhost:5874`) when I run the service locally from Visual Studio, but not after I publish and run the exe.

I'm using the Options pattern with DI...

```c#
private readonly Uri _serverAddress;

public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptions<ServerSettings> serverSettings)
{
    _serverAddress = serverSettings.Value.ServerAddress;
}
```

```c#
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync($"{_serverAddress}api/Importapi", stoppingToken);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

The thing I can't understand is why `_serverAddress` gets populated when I'm running via Visual Studio, but after I publish, `_serverAddress` is null. I'm not sure if it's relevant that in both cases, the server variable is the same: `localhost:5874`, as I'm simply trying to get the service to run on my local machine to talk to a web app, which is also running on localhost under a different port.

When I run publish, the deployment mode is "self contained", I'm running on x64, producing a single file, ReadyToRun compilation...

So what could be causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this may be a Visual Studio bug, since the command line version does not have this issue. In other words, if I publish via the command line: `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true` then the appsettings.json goes with it.